# How to integrate Elasticsearch and PgSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, elasticsearch

I have to push data from PgSQL to Elasticsearch? Tell any other method than CLI for indexing method

Comment: what is your technology stack? How you connect to postgresql usually. If by any chance you are on ruby, take a look at this https://github.com/toptal/chewy.

Comment: No, actually I am connecting through pgAdmin4 application, and trying to push data from pgsql tables to elasticsearch.

Comment: https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb

Comment: Did you take a look to logstash (https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin)